# What is Google search engine interested in on HTML pages?

Tags: seo, google, html, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)

I know there are meta keywords, HTML structure, and site map but what else is Google interested in?

Answer (score 6):

Content, content, content, headlines, links, content, content, links, content, content, and perhaps meta keywords.

Comment: its all in html structure of the page but  is ther anything else?

Answer (score 2):

Everything. Outgoing links, their context, non-repeated content and tons, tons more. Find some SEO-related resources for detailed info.

Comment: It's also interested in repeated content to see if it's a spam site or not too!

Answer (score 1):

Title, Body, Metatags and other people's links to your websites.

Answer (score 1):

Also, consider setting up landing pages for specific keywords. Google is interested in relevancy above almost all else. Have pages specificly design to target relevant keywords, with uber relevant content. Google will thank you for it.

Answer (score 1):

Google has posted a [SEO starter guide](http://www.google.com/webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) (pdf) which spells out in detail which parts of a site they recommend optimizing first.

Comment: Very helpful resource for those attempting to start SEO on their site.